# Regex for strings nearby other strings?

Tags: regex, shell, awk, grep, pcre

I want to write a flexible regex for `grep` that will return search terms found within a certain distance from each other.

The ideal behavior is something like research databases; for example, where you can search for articles that have `capital` and `GDP` within 15 words of each other, which would include articles where the strings `capital` and `GDP` may be separated by five, six, seven, etc., alphanumeric strings of unspecified length. The regex statement would include punctuation (e.g., commas, periods, hyphens), but also accent marks and diacritics. So, results where `chechè` and `lavi` are no more than five strings apart.

I imagine the statement will involve lookaheads, and phrases like `{1,15}`, or maybe piping one `grep` thru another `grep`, but that loses the benefit of `GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'`. Constructing it is really beyond my skill set. I have a set of .txt documents that I want to run the search over, but making the regex flexible to change the distance between strings or to truncate the terms would also be useful for others who have things like fieldnotes or reading notes in a standard format.

**EDIT**

Below is a sample of passages taken from the Bible.

```
Ye shall buy meat of them for money, that ye may eat; and ye shall also buy water of them for money, that ye may drink. For the Lord thy God hath blessed thee in all the works of thy hand: he knoweth thy walking through this great wilderness: these forty years the Lord thy God hath been with thee; thou hast lacked nothing... Thou shalt sell me meat for money, that I may eat; and give me water for money, that I may drink: only I will pass through on my feet: (as the children of Esau which dwell in Seir, and the Moabites which dwell in Ar, did unto me:) until I shall pass over Jordan into the land which the Lord our God giveth us. But Sihon king of Heshbon would not let us pass by him: for the Lord thy God hardened his spirit, and made his heart obstinate, that he might deliver him into thy hand, as appeareth this day. And the Lord said unto me, Behold, I have begun to give Sihon and his land before thee: begin to possess, that thou mayest inherit his land. Then Sihon came out against us, he and all his people, to fight at Jahaz. And the Lord our God delivered him before us; and we smote him, and his sons, and all his people. And if the way be too long for thee, so that thou art not able to carry it; or if the place be too far from thee, which the Lord thy God shall choose to set his name there, when the Lord thy God hath blessed thee: then shalt thou turn it into money, and bind up the money in thine hand, and shalt go unto the place which the Lord thy God shall choose: and thou shalt bestow that money for whatsoever thy soul lusteth after, for oxen, or for sheep, or for wine, or for strong drink, or for whatsoever thy soul desireth: and thou shalt eat there before the Lord thy God, and thou shalt rejoice, thou, and thine household, and the Levite that is within thy gates; thou shalt not forsake him: for he hath no part nor inheritance with thee... Now it came to pass, that at what time the chest was brought unto the king’s office by the hand of the Levites, and when they saw that there was much money, the king’s scribe and the high priest’s officer came and emptied the chest, and took it, and carried it to his place again. Thus they did day by day, and gathered money in abundance. And when they had finished it, they brought the rest of the money before the king and Jehoiada, whereof were made vessels for the house of the Lord , even vessels to minister, and to offer withal, and spoons, and vessels of gold and silver. And they offered burnt offerings in the house of the Lord continually all the days of Jehoiada. Thou hast bought me no sweet cane with money, neither hast thou filled me with the fat of thy sacrifices; but thou hast made me to serve with thy sins, thou hast wearied me with thine iniquities... Howbeit there were not made for the house of the Lord bowls of silver, snuffers, basins, trumpets, any vessels of gold, or vessels of silver, of the money that was brought into the house of the Lord: but they gave that to the workmen, and repaired therewith the house of the Lord. Moreover they reckoned not with the men, into whose hand they delivered the money to be bestowed on workmen: for they dealt faithfully. The trespass money and sin money was not brought into the house of the Lord: it was the priests’.
```

If I wanted to grep for instances of where `shalt` and `money` are co-present within five words (including punctuation), how would I write that regex?

I'm not sure how to give expected results since `grep --context=1` would include more than just the strings with 0-5 strings in between, but I imagine the results would identify:

```
shalt sell me meat for money
shalt thou turn it into money
money in thine hand, and shalt
shalt bestow that money
```

But would not return `shall buy meat of them for money,` since 'money' appears as the sixth string.

Comment: Include your sample input with expected output

Comment: @anubhava added sample text

Comment: gave expected output @EdMorton

Comment: wrt `I want to write a flexible regex for grep` - is that really what you want or do you just want a sensible solution to your problem?

Comment: @EdMorton i do want a sensible solution, but it should be flexible enough to alter easily for desired changes in word proximity or to truncate, and so I felt grepping was that option. I'm certainly open to more sensible alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not grep but this seems to do what you asked for using GNU awk for multi-char RS and word boundaries:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS="^$"
    split(words,word)
}
{
    gsub(/@/,"@A"); gsub(/{/,"@B"); gsub(/}/,"@C")
    gsub("\\<"word[1]"\\>","{")
    gsub("\\<"word[2]"\\>","}")
    while ( match($0,/{[^{}]+}|}[^{}]+{/) ) {
        tgt =  substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/}/,word[2],tgt)
        gsub(/{/,word[1],tgt)
        gsub(/@C/,"}",tgt); gsub(/@B/,"{",tgt); gsub(/@A/,"@",tgt)
        if ( gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"&",tgt) <= range ) {
            print tgt
        }
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+length(word[1]))
    }
}

$ awk -v words='money shalt' -v range=5 -f tst.awk file
shalt sell me meat for money
shalt thou turn it into money
money in thine hand, and shalt
shalt bestow that money

$ awk -v words='and him' -v range=10 -f tst.awk file
him: for the Lord thy God hardened his spirit, and
and made his heart obstinate, that he might deliver him
him before us; and
and we smote him
him, and
```

Note that the above works even with input like `shalt sell me meat for money in thine hand, and shalt` where one of the words (`money`) appears 5 words after the first occurrence of the other word (`shalt`) AND 5 words before a second occurrence of that first word (again, `shalt`):

```
$  echo 'shalt sell me meat for money in thine hand, and shalt' |
    awk -v words='shalt money' -v range=5 -f tst.awk
shalt sell me meat for money
money in thine hand, and shalt
```

---

For colors, file names, and line numbers:

Do this to see the colors available to you in your terminal (each line will be output in a different color):

```
$ for ((c=0; c<$(tput colors); c++)); do tput setaf "$c"; tput setaf "$c" | cat -v; echo "=$c"; done; tput setaf 0
^[[30m=0
^[[31m=1
^[[32m=2
^[[33m=3
^[[34m=4
^[[35m=5
^[[36m=6
^[[37m=7
```

Now that you can see what those escape sequences and numbers mean, update the awk script to (`\033` = `^[` = Esc):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS="^$"
    split(words,word)
    c["black"]  = "\033[30m"
    c["red"]    = "\033[31m"
    c["green"]  = "\033[32m"
    c["yellow"] = "\033[33m"
    c["blue"]   = "\033[34m"
    c["pink"]   = "\033[35m"
    c["teal"]   = "\033[36m"
    c["grey"]   = "\033[37m"
    for (color in c) {
        print c[color] color c["black"]
    }
}
{
    gsub(/@/,"@A"); gsub(/{/,"@B"); gsub(/}/,"@C")
    gsub("\\<"word[1]"\\>","{")
    gsub("\\<"word[2]"\\>","}")
    while ( match($0,/{[^{}]+}|}[^{}]+{/) ) {
        tgt =  substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/}/,word[2],tgt)
        gsub(/{/,word[1],tgt)
        gsub(/@C/,"}",tgt); gsub(/@B/,"{",tgt); gsub(/@A/,"@",tgt)
        if ( gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"&",tgt) <= range ) {
            print FILENAME, FNR, c["red"] tgt c["black"]
        }
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+length(word[1]))
    }
}
```

and when you run it you'll see a dump of all available colors and for each of your target text it will be preceded by the file name and line number within that file and the text will be colored in red:

[image]

Comment: your solution works for my simple example! but i don't know `awk` at all - is it possible to iterate this over a set of files?

Comment: yessir. but i'll try to read more of the manual to find color options and to get awk to print the file names (and line numbers?) of search hits

Comment: running your script on a folder of .rtf works nicely, but it doesn't print diacritics & accents well (maybe this is a terminal setting i've fubbed?) and it doesn't seem to report the line numbers correctly.

Comment: can you please help me revise my expectations when using your script on [this sample](https://gist.github.com/badgrad/6c75eda9d30a18a7b9e2cb0eaaaa2ffc) and the regexes 'bricks ruins'? When I run it, the result indicates `sample.txt 1 bricks. Scattered about the vicinity are fragments of wòch ravèt and brick. Mozà says there are more ruins`, which I take to mean line 1, but the terms are found on line 7.

Comment: WRT diacritics and accents, it appears only when running the script over .rtf files, not .txt

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. In the sample input you posted you had all the text on a single line so I assumed that's how you wanted it treated and so the script reads the whole file as a single "line" (actually record) and so the match is always reported as being on the first "line". Edit your question to show how the tool should work on multi-paragraph, multi-line input if that's what you have (e.g. include cases where the first word is on one line and the second word is on the next line or paragraph).

Comment: wrt ".rtf" files - awk and grep are designed to operate on files that are POSIX text files. I don't really know what a ".rtf" file contains but I THINK it's some Windows thing with text and formatting commands in it and if it's not POSIX text lines only then I wouldn't expect awk or grep to be able to operate on it.

Comment: I should have mentioned - if you just want the input treated line by line (so potential matches that cross lines will not be reported) then just delete the line that says `RS="^$"` from the top of the script as that is what's telling awk to read the whole file as a single "line" (record).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
`grep 'shalt\W\+\(\w\+\W\+\)\{0,5\}money'`

Maybe in both directions:
`grep 'shalt\W\+\(\w\+\W\+\)\{0,5\}money\|money\W\+\(\w\+\W\+\)\{0,5\}shalt'`

https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html:

> ‘\w’
>
> Match word constituent, it is a synonym for ‘[_[:alnum:]]’.
>
> ‘\W’
>
> Match non-word constituent, it is a synonym for ‘[^_[:alnum:]]’.

Generic answer to construct the grep dynamicly, in this case with a shell function:

```
find_adjacent() {
    dist="$1"; shift
    grep1="$1"; shift
    grep2="$1"; shift
    
    between='\W\+\(\w\+\W\+\)\{0,'"$dist"'\}'
    regex="$grep1$between$grep2\|$grep2$between$grep1"
    
    printf 'Using the regex: %s\n' "$regex" 1>&2
    grep "$regex" "$@"
}
```

Example usage:

```
echo 'shalt sell me meat for money
shalt thou turn it into money
money in thine hand, and shalt
shalt bestow that money
capital and GDP' | find_adjacent 3 shalt money -i --color=auto
```

or to match across lines:

```
find_adjacent 5 shalt money -z file_with_the_bible_passages.txt
```

---

## Edit

As [pointed out by EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263306/regex-for-strings-nearby-other-strings/52279672#comment91510514_52279672) this only finds the first part of a continues match. It would still match the right line, but color highlighting would be of a bit.

To fix this the regex will get more complicated because it has to match any continues "shalt ... money ... shalt" in 4 cases:

- "shalt ... money ... shalt"
- "shalt ... money ... shalt ... money"
- "money ... shalt ... money"
- "money ... shalt ... money ... shalt"

This can be done by replacing the `regex=...` line with:

```
regex1="$grep1\($between$grep2$between$grep1\)\+"
regex2="$grep1$between$grep2\($between$grep1$between$grep2\)*"
regex3="$grep2\($between$grep1$between$grep2\)\+"
regex4="$grep2$between$grep1\($between$grep2$between$grep1\)*"
regex="$regex1\|$regex2\|$regex3\|$regex4"
```

Additionally it might be mixed up like this:
"shalt xxx shalt xxx money xxx money"

With a distance of max 3 words between, the above regex still would only find:
"shalt xxx shalt xxx money"

To mach those cases the only viable solution is, to only match the words themself and use look-aheads/look-behinds (needs more advanced implementation of regex e.g. GNU grep's `-P` for perl regular expressions):

```
find_adjacent() {
    dist="$1"; shift
    word1="$1"; shift
    word2="$1"; shift
    
    ahead='\W+(\w+\W+){0,'"$dist"'}'
    behind='(\W+\w+){0,'"$dist"'}\W+'
    regex="$word1(?=$ahead$word2)|(?<=$word2)$behind\K$word1|$word2(?=$ahead$word1)|(?<=$word1)$behind\K$word2"
    
    printf 'Using the regex: %s\n' "$regex" 1>&2
    grep -P "$regex" "$@"
}
```

Another example usage (search case insensitive, display filename and line, highlight the words found, search all files in a directory):

```
find_adjacent 15 capital GDP -i -Hn --color=auto -r folder_to_search
```

Comment: Try that with input like `shalt sell me meat for money in thine hand, and shalt` where one of the words (`money`) appears 5 words after the first occurrence of the other word (`shalt`) AND 5 words before a second occurrence of that first word (again, `shalt`).

Comment: btw  - if you use `grep -E` then you won't have to escape all the ERE metachars in your regexp to activate them.

Comment: @EdMorton: Good point, that would break the the `-o` example, and `--color=auto` might be a bit of. But for the OP's "... research databases; for example, where you can search for articles that have ..." it should work

Comment: not sure what that means. oh, and you'll also need `-z` to match strings that cross lines.

Comment: @EdMorton: The `-z` is optional, I edited the example to reflect that behaviour.

Comment: Without the `-z` grep will only read 1 line at a time so without `-z` the script coudn't find the match in, say `printf 'shalt make\nplenty money\n' | find_adjacent 5 shalt money`. Be aware that [according to the providers](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) `-P` is "highly experimental" and it has been known to cause core dumps. I expected you to fix the "word in the middle" issue with just 2 separate greps - `grep 'shalt.*money'` then `grep 'money.*shalt'`